# How to convert a column with "character set latin1 collate latin1_bin" into utf8 in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Ok, in the existing table,

```
CREATE TABLE tb(id int, `text` varchar(255) character set latin1 collate latin1_bin default NULL)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want to make the `text` column to be `utf8` and it supports Case Sensitive for `select` query

Suppose there is "`ã`" & "`Ã`" which is `utf8` in the `text` column

```
id - text
1  - ã
2  - Ã
```

, and when user `select * from tb where text='Ã'`it should show record with id=2 only

Is this query the correct one

```
alter table tb modify column text varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci default NULL
```

I have no idea what `utf8_general_ci` means? am i doing cortrectly?

Comment: you want to convert latin1 to utf ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the `Alter` Command.

Like `ALTER TABLE urtable MODIFY col1 VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;`

See [column charset conversion here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-conversion.html)

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct one

```
alter table tb modify text varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin default NULL
```